# How to properly format JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I asked a question earlier, which all revolved around a JSON formatting problem. I have a PHP page, which just grabs rows from a MYSQL database, and returns them. However, i'm unsure how to format them so all the columns I get are a set, and for each row, it creates a new set. I'm not sure what is common practice to do to encode things like this.

e.g. this is what I want (if it is even correct):

```
{ "message": [
   {
      "chat":"Hello, world!",
      "time":"2014-05-09 17:32:00",
       "username":"Josue"
   },
   {
      "chat":"This is my second message.",
      "time":"2014-05-09 17:32:05",
      "username":"Josue"
   }
]
}
```

That way, I can parse using $.parseAJAX, and get access to my data like: `data.message[0].chat`, and it would return "Hello world!".

Here is what I am currently doing:

```
$SQL = sprintf('SELECT time_sent, chat, username FROM Messages where time_sent >= date(\'%s\')', $last_chat_time);
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

$messages = Array();

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
    $messages[] = 'chat';
    $messages[] = $row['chat'];
    $messages[] = 'time';
    $messages[] = $row['time_sent'];
    $messages[] = 'username';
    $messages[] = $row['username'];
}

$loopCount = count($chats);

if(count($messages) > 0){
/*
    $sexyJSON = '{message: [';
    for($i = 0; $i < $loopCount; $i++){
        $sexyJSON .= '{"chat":"'.$chats[$i].'","time":"'.$times[$i].'","username":"'.$usernames[$i].'"},';
    }
    $sexyJSON = substr($sexyJSON,0,strlen($sexyJSON)-1);
    $sexyJSON .= ']}';
    $newMessages = $sexyJSON;
    echo $sexyJSON;
    */

     echo json_encode($messages);
}
```

When I simply encode my array, it returns something like this:

```
["chat","Hello, world!","time","2014-05-09 17:32:00","username","Josue","chat","hmmm","time","2014-05-09 17:48:34","username","asdf"]
```

What would I have to do to group chat with the message, date with the date, and username with the username in a key-value pair?

Comment: What do you mean by "format?" This does not sound like a "formatting" problem.

Comment: Sorry, I will try to clarify my question.

Comment: Your JSON is definetely valid (you could check http://jsonlint.com/) to be sure

Comment: Using the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` option in your `json_encode()` statement will guarantee that the resulting JSON is well-formed and makes it a bit easier to read if you decide to output it for troubleshooting purposes.
<http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format of the mysql_fetch_assoc should be

```
array('chat'=>'Some chat', 'time_sent'=>'123456', 'username'=>'abcdefg')
```

json_encode would directly translate this to

```
{"chat":"Some chat", "time_sent":"123456", "username":"abcdefg"}
```

So in your loop, if you simply do `$mesages[] = $row;` and leave your json_encode call as-is, it should work as shown above. However, you can alter your SQL statement to give the columns an alias so that `time_sent` simply shows as the property `time`

Comment: In my ajax, when `data` is returned as a parameter when it successfully, how would I access a column? data.chat[0]?

Comment: ^^ see my answer below, at the end of my answer

Comment: Josue, in this case, data would be an array. Assuming that your array only contains one element, it would look something like this: `[{"chat":"Some chat", "time_sent":"123456", "username":"abcdefg"}]`. So you can iterate through this with something akin to `for (var i in data) console.log(data[i].chat);`

Answer (score 2):

This is what i would do:

```
$SQL = sprintf('SELECT time_sent, chat, username FROM Messages where time_sent >= date(\'%s\')', $last_chat_time);
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

$messages = array();

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
  $arr = array();
  $arr['chat'] = $row['chat'];
  $arr['time'] = $row['time_sent'];
  $arr['username'] = $row['username'];
  $messages[] = $arr;
}

$loopCount = count($chats);

if(count($messages) > 0){
    echo json_encode($messages);
}
```

This will output if not encoded:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [chat] => chat_0
            [time] => time_sent_0
            [username] => username_0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [chat] => chat_1
            [time] => time_sent_1
            [username] => username_1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [chat] => chat_2
            [time] => time_sent_2
            [username] => username_2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [chat] => chat_3
            [time] => time_sent_3
            [username] => username_3
        )
```

)

And this if encoded:

```
[{"chat":"chat_0","time":"time_sent_0","username":"username_0"},
 {"chat":"chat_1","time":"time_sent_1","username":"username_1"},
 {"chat":"chat_2","time":"time_sent_2","username":"username_2"},
 {"chat":"chat_3","time":"time_sent_3","username":"username_3"}]
```

To parse the JSON

lets say you have your JSON results in a `data` var

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(data);

$.each(obj, function(i, value){
    console.log(value.chat);    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to work with multi-dimensional arrays in order to get this to work. The code below has been edited to assign values to named indexes and append these to the 2nd level to the $messages array.

```
$messages = Array();

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
    $messages[] = Array(
        'chat' => $row['chat'],
        'time' => $row['time_sent'],
        'username' => $row['username']
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed, I'm just not familiar enough with multi-dimensional arrays. Will accept your answer when the timer is up.

Answer (score 1):

The while cycle should be like this:

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
  $arr = array();
  $arr['chat'] = $row['chat'];
  $arr['time'] = $row['time_sent'];
  $arr['username'] = $row['username'];
  $messages[] = $arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save a little time by getting the field names correct within the SQL.

```
$SQL = sprintf('SELECT time_sent as `time`, chat, username FROM Messages where time_sent >= date(\'%s\')', $last_chat_time);
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

$messages = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $messages[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($messages);
```

IMO returning an empty array when there are no messages is better than returning nothing, as now you have a way to differentiate if your php worked vs if you had no messages, from within your JavaScript code.